# keyboard notification not called in ios 11.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, keyboard

I have keyboard notification in my App and its working fine in ios 10 but my notification method not called in ios11.3
Below is my code:

```
- (void)attach {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    UIView* responder = [self findFirstResponder];
    if (responder) {
        _tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapAnywhere:)];
        [baseView addGestureRecognizer:_tapRecognizer];
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
        CGRect screenRect = [RGLayout layout].fullScreen;
        CGRect frame      = responder.frame ;
    }
}
```

I have tried to find the solution and i got that the only changes in iOS11 is `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` for keyborad height.

But my problem is that my keyboardWasShown not called in ios11.3 same code is working ios 10.2

FYI: when user click on next the next textField will becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: I have tested with 11.4 and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but the behaviour is strange the notification is calling in one screen and not in another screen.

I have solve the issue by following code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (self.nextField) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.nextField becomeFirstResponder];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:self];
        });
    }
    else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [textField resignFirstResponder] ;
        });
    }
    return NO ;
}
```